# How to format print function in Java to print equal width per different number?

Tags: java, printing, formatting

Given these variables:

```
int a = 1, b = 123, c = 55, d= 1231;
```

Is there a way in Java to print them with a set width of 5, say. In case number is less than five digits - only print dashes.

```
1----,123--,55---,1231-
```

I am aware that these can be achieved with some loops and if statements, looking for something similar to setw() from C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.out.println(String.format("%-5.5s", s).replace(" ", "-"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't do it directly.   Java has functionality broadly similar to that of C's "printf" formatting.

You can set a field width, you can justify left or right, but your fill characters are limited to zero and space.

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

If the format uses the general "%s" directive, and the corresponding argument is of a class under your control, then you can implement a 'formatTo' method to do the conversion.  So a wrapper class might be useful to you.